# looping through ex post cumsums

Tags: arrays, loops, indexing, cumsum

Say I have an array

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to calculate the element-wise difference such that the resultant array will be like:

first element stays the same

```
result = [1, ...
```

second element will be second input element minus cum sum of whats currently in the result vector so 2-1 = 1

so eventually for this particular input you get

```
result = [1,1,1,1,1]
```

I thought about using

```
[y - x.cumsum[x] for x, y in zip(R, R[1:])]
```

didn't work alternatively settled on

```
np.array(d1)[1:]-np.cumsum(np.array(d1))[:-1]
```

This too is incorrect. I would appreciate your help. ty